# How to delete lots of mongodb collections at once?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, database

There are a lot of mongodb collections in my database that I need to delete. They all have similar names, and it would be easy to delete them if only wildcard characters could be used. But it doesn't look like they can.

Is there a way to select a bunch of collections at once to delete them?

Answer (score 33):

For regex you can use string.match

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(c) {
    if(!c.match("^system.indexes")) { 
        db.getCollection(c).drop();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Check your regex. Your example will drop the `system.indexes` collection. I'm assuming you intended this to drop everything except `system.indexes`.

Comment: @wyattisimo you are right, the regex matches `system.indexes`, and yes the intention is to drop everything except `system.indexes`. Thanks!
I've fixed the code.

Answer (score 16):

```
# Delete Particular Collections From MongoDB

> use database_name

> delete_collection_list = ["collection1", "collection2", "collection3", "collection4", "collection5", "collection6"]

> delete_collection_list.forEach( function (collection) {
    if (db.getCollectionNames().indexOf(collection)>=0) {
        db.getCollection(collection).drop();
        print("Deleted Collection: "+ collection);
    }
  })
```

Comment: Use `db.getCollection(collection)` instead of `db[collection]` to avoid error when collection name is a reserved keyword (ex. 'group')

Comment: This did nothing, do indents have to match and do I need a semicolon after the last parantheses?

Comment: Couldn't you have just formatted the code normally? This is way overcomplicated

Answer (score 10):

You can delete all the collections using the following command.

```
> use database_name;

> db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(c) {
    if(c != 'system.indexes') { 
        db.getCollection(c).drop();
    }
  });
```

Comment: That's still one-by-one, and there's no regex :)

Answer (score 7):

No, there's not a way to drop several collections by a wildcard/regex. You have to drop them one by one. I recently performed a similar task and my script was able to drop ~20-30 collections per second. How many do you have?

Answer (score 4):

You can drop **every** collection in the database with `db.dropDatabase()` in the mongo shell. Just make sure you really want to nuke everything before you do.