# Dropping MongoDB collections using regex

Tags: mongodb

is it possible? I have auto-generated mongoDB collections that at a certain moment I need to drop. I know their collection name patterns and they are too many, so dropping them by hand is not an option. All examples I had a look at using regex were involving queries but not with database commands. I know I could iterate over all collections and filtering by their name I could get it working but I am looking for a more handy and single command (I want to use it directly in the shell), if possible :)

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: check these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206890/how-to-delete-lots-of-mongodb-collections-at-once

Comment: When you auto-generate and auto-drop a lot of collections you are likely doing something wrong.

Comment: @Philipp it's a pretty concrete use case :)

Comment: @3boll thanks for the link, missed that in my quick threads search!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do it using MongoDB console:

```
regExp = /test/;
db.getCollectionNames().filter(function(name){
  return name.match(regExp)
}).forEach(function(name){
  db.getCollection(name).drop()
});
```

You can use any regexp to match your collections names.

Comment: You're right, seems to be the only working approach (I wanted to avoid it though). If no other possible solutions are provided soon, I will accept it as an answer. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5):

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(c) {
    if(c.match("^system.indexes")) { 
        db.getCollection(c).drop();
    }
  });
```