# How to delete multiple collection in Robomongo

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I am using Robomongo for MongoDB.
In my Robomongo I have multiple duplicate collections.
Now I want to delete each collection at a time without any query and ForEach function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete lots of mongodb collections at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206890/how-to-delete-lots-of-mongodb-collections-at-once)

Comment: I want to delete collections at a time without any query and Foreach function.

Comment: You cannot do that . RoboMongo does not allow to select multiple collections from the UI by using ctrl+click.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to the current available version of the S/w, i doubt if its possible.
https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/608

But you might be interested in viewing:
[How to delete lots of mongodb collections at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206890/how-to-delete-lots-of-mongodb-collections-at-once)