# Is there a way to delete all collections in a database except the one ? nodejs mongodb, mongoose

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am having multiple collections inside a single database. I have basically created collections name by current date like 20220829, 20220830, 20220831 (these are collection names). I want to keep only 20220831 collection (the latest one) and basically delete all others in that database. Is there a way to do this optimally?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete lots of mongodb collections at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206890/how-to-delete-lots-of-mongodb-collections-at-once)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer following code snip

```
afterEach(async function () {

var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

let todaysDate = yyyy+mm+dd

const collections = await mongoose.connection.db.collections()

  for (let collection of collections) {
    if(collection !== todaysDate)
    await collection.remove();
  }
})
```